# How to simplify for loops using matrix multiplication?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, for-loop, matrix

Is there a more efficient way to replace these 2 for loops with matrix multiplication?

```
def cost_func(x, y):
     
    for i in range(24):
        for j in range(24):
            cost = np.sum(W[i][j]*(y[j] - x[i]))       
    
    return cost
```

W is a matrix (25,25) and x,y are vectors with 25 elements.

Comment: That can't be the right code.  You compute `cost` 576 times, then throw away all but the last one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not 100% sure what you are trying to achieve here since as @Tim Roberts pointed out you are not saving the costs. Also the `np.sum` is confusing assuming `x` and `y` are 1d vectors. But if they are 1d vectors you could do:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.arange(24)
y = np.arange(24)
W = np.random.uniform(0, 1, (24, 24))
cost = (W * (y.reshape(1, -1) - x.reshape(-1, 1)))

# cost[i][j] = W[i][j]*(y[j] - x[i])
```

Answer (score 1):

numpy supports a matrix multiply operator, @.  I think you can get what you want by:

```
C:\tmp>python
Python 3.7.3 (v3.7.3:ef4ec6ed12, Mar 25 2019, 22:22:05) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = np.arange(3).reshape(1,3)
>>> y = np.arange(4)
>>> W = np.ones((3,4))
>>> (-x)@W@y
array([-18.])
>>>
```

Comment: OP also mentioned a `W` in the formula

Comment: Yes, his `W` is my `z`.  I'll change it.

Comment: Actually I am not sure if `y` and `x` are vectors since OP used `np.sum` on the seemingly scalar values. Also I think your answer is equivalent to `sum(-wij*xi*yj)`?